# Configure or extend log4net SmtpAppender with custom subjects

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

How can I specify a layout and conversionPattern for the resulting emails subject?

The BufferSize will need to be less than or equal to 1 so no buffering will occur.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The CodeProject article [log4net NonBufferedSmtpAppenderWithSubjectLayout](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/log4net_SmtpAppender.aspx) looks promising.

---

By inheriting from the required base appender (SmtpPickupDirAppender in my case) and adding a ILayout property it is possible to change the Subject in the Append method.

```cs
public class SmtpSubjectLayoutPickupDirAppender : log4net.Appender.SmtpPickupDirAppender
{
    public SmtpSubjectLayoutPickupDirAppender()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public ILayout SubjectLayout
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void Append(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (this.BufferSize <= 1 && this.SubjectLayout != null)
        {
            StringWriter subjectWriter = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            this.SubjectLayout.Format(subjectWriter, loggingEvent);
            this.Subject = subjectWriter.ToString();
        }

        base.Append(loggingEvent);
    }
}
```

This can then be configured by specifying a subjectLayout property to override the default subject.

```xml
<appender name="SmtpPickupDirAppender" type="namespace.for.SmtpSubjectLayoutPickupDirAppender">
    <to value="to@domain.com" />
    <from value="from@domain.com" />
    <subject value="test logging message" />

    <subjectLayout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="Logging message - %message"/>
    </subjectLayout>

    <pickupDir value="C:\SmtpPickup" />
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <lossy value="true" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="WARN"/>
    </evaluator>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: For custom properties: <conversionPattern value="Logging message - %property{myVal}"/> ThreadContext.Properties["myVal"] = "whatever";

Comment: `public ILayout SubjectLayout` needs to be `public PatternLayout SubjectLayout` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/l4n_sa_subject.aspx) another example of SmtpAppender with custom subjects.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from [Nuget](https://github.com/AlexanderByndyu/log4net.SmtpAppenderWithSubjectLayout)

[Source code and example](https://github.com/AlexanderByndyu/log4net.SmtpAppenderWithSubjectLayout)

Answer (score 0):

Because the previous answeres that suggests using NuGet version of SmtpAppenderWithSubjectLayout needs log4net version > 1.2.1, I've used the NuGet source code but modified it to use the log4net 1.2.1

```cs
public class SmtpAppenderWithSubjectLayout : SmtpAppender
{
    public PatternLayout SubjectLayout { get; set; }

    protected override void SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
    {
        PrepareSubject(events);

        base.SendBuffer(events);
    }

    protected virtual void PrepareSubject(IEnumerable<LoggingEvent> events)
    {
        var subjects = new List<string>();

        foreach (LoggingEvent @event in events)
        {
            if (Evaluator.IsTriggeringEvent(@event))
            {
                var subjectWriter = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                SubjectLayout.Format(subjectWriter, @event);
                subjects.Add(subjectWriter.ToString());
            }
        }

        Subject = string.Join(", ", subjects.ToArray());
    }
}
```