# Multiple smtphost addresses using smtpAppender in log4net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, logging, log4net

I want to be able to specify multiple smtp server host addresses and implement a logic whereby if email using one smtp server fails, it tries to send using the next smtp server address. Is it possible using log4net. Can we override some functions of log4net and implement our own logic in it to send emails?

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="group@ivp.in" />
  <from value="uname@ivp.in" />
  <subject>Error Notification</subject>
  **<smtpHost value="10.0.0.12, 10.0.0.13" />**
  <authentication value="None" />
  <port value="25" />
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <EnableSsl value="false"/>
  <lossy value="true" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="ERROR"/>
  </evaluator>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%newline%exception" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: You can _override_ the `SmtpAppender` class and decide the value of the `smtpHost` using conditional statements (if/else). Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67433757/11671912) for further details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible only if you implement `custom SmtpAppender`.

I have copied `CustomSmtpAppender` code from [Log4net sourcecode Examples.](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html) hopefullly this will help you.

don't forget to refer `CustomSmtpAppender` in your app config

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mail;

using log4net.Layout;
using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Appender;

namespace SampleAppendersApp.Appender
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Simple mail appender that sends individual messages
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This SimpleSmtpAppender sends each LoggingEvent received as a
    /// separate mail message.
    /// The mail subject line can be specified using a pattern layout.
    /// </remarks>
    public class SimpleSmtpAppender : AppenderSkeleton
    {
        public SimpleSmtpAppender()
        {   
        }

        public string To 
        {
            get { return m_to; }
            set { m_to = value; }
        }

        public string From 
        {
            get { return m_from; }
            set { m_from = value; }
        }

        public PatternLayout Subject 
        {
            get { return m_subjectLayout; }
            set { m_subjectLayout = value; }
        }

        public string SmtpHost
        {
            get { return m_smtpHost; }
            set { m_smtpHost = value; }
        }

        #region Override implementation of AppenderSkeleton

        override protected void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) 
        {
            try 
            {     
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                string t = Layout.Header;
                if (t != null)
                {
                    writer.Write(t);
                }

                // Render the event and append the text to the buffer
                RenderLoggingEvent(writer, loggingEvent);

                t = Layout.Footer;
                if (t != null)
                {
                    writer.Write(t);
                }

                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                mailMessage.Body = writer.ToString();
                mailMessage.From = m_from;
                mailMessage.To = m_to;

                if (m_subjectLayout == null)
                {
                    mailMessage.Subject = "Missing Subject Layout";
                }
                else
                {
                    StringWriter subjectWriter = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    m_subjectLayout.Format(subjectWriter, loggingEvent);
                    mailMessage.Subject = subjectWriter.ToString();
                }

                if (m_smtpHost != null && m_smtpHost.Length > 0)
                {
                    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = m_smtpHost;
                }

                SmtpMail.Send(mailMessage);
            } 
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                ErrorHandler.Error("Error occurred while sending e-mail notification.", e);
            }       
        }

        override protected bool RequiresLayout
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        #endregion // Override implementation of AppenderSkeleton

        private string m_to;
        private string m_from;
        private PatternLayout m_subjectLayout;
        private string m_smtpHost;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! just what i was looking for. Now i can implement my own smtp handler the way i want. Thanks

Answer (score 48):

There is an easier way

```
<to value="group@ivp.in,group2@ivp.in,group3@ivp.in,group4@ivp.in" />
```

Comment: The question was `I want to be able to specify multiple smtp server host addresses`, not multiple `to` addresses

Comment: Okay. But my answer is my answer useful for some users:)

Comment: this might be not the answer to op's question, but it is the answer I was searching for when I landed here. 18 upvotes vs 4 tells that most people here were in the same boat

Comment: Same here.. its not the answer for the op's question but its the one I needed.

Comment: This is the one I needed :)

Comment: This is not the way stackoverflow works. You should post this answer into the question it responds to. Here it doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late for the party, but I had a similar problem that required me to solve it programmatically instead of hard coding them directly into the `app.config` file.

This is the approach you want to use when you don't want to expose your email credentials through the configuration file. It's also useful if you want to override SmtpAppender for any reason.

Here's the log4net appender settings for the `app.config`:

```json
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="MyNameSpace.SmtpAppenderHelper">
    <to value="sendto@company.com" />
    <cc value="sendccto@company.com" />
    <subject value="An Error Occured" />
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <EnableSsl value="true" />
    <lossy value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%level %date - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="ERROR" />
    </evaluator>
</appender>
```

My helper class:

```cs
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class SmtpAppenderHelper : SmtpAppender
    {
        protected override void SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
        {
            // overriding the SmtpAppender so that I can add some sensitive information
            this.Username = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
            this.Password = "NotSafePassword";
            this.SmtpHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
            this.Port = 587;
            this.Authentication = SmtpAuthentication.Basic;
            this.From = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";

            base.SendBuffer(events);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also create a method of `SmtpAppenderHelper` class to help you modify the email subject and fire it before the `base.SendBuffer(events)` method to modify the subject like so:

```cs
protected virtual void prepareSubject(ICollection<LoggingEvent> events)
{
    Subject = null;
    foreach (LoggingEvent _event in events)
    {
        if (Evaluator.IsTriggeringEvent(_event))
        {
            string msg = _event.ExceptionObject == null ? _event.RenderedMessage : _event.ExceptionObject.Message;

            Subject = string.Format("[{0}] {1}", _event.Level, msg);

            break;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Another [example here on overriding the `Appenders`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902060/configure-or-extend-log4net-smtpappender-with-custom-subjects/)