# Log4net- dynamic configuration properties for smtpAppender

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I use log4net for send mails to my app users.
I must to have dynamic configuration for doing it.
So I tried using GlobalContext.Properties for this, but it doesn't work!

Here is my code of original appender:

```
   <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="myAddress@myComp.com" />
  <from value="myAddress@myComp.com" />
  <subject value="test logging message" />
  <smtpHost value="out.bezeqint.net" />
  <username value="myUserName" />
  <password value="myPassword />
  <authentication value="Basic" />
  <bufferSize value="512" />
  <lossy value="true" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="ERROR" />
  </evaluator>
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="WARN" />
  </evaluator>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %newline%newline - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

at c#:

```
  ILog emailLog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("EmailLogger"); 
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(emailLog.Logger.Repository);

        emailLog.Error("test aaa");
```

It works well.
But, I tried to replace one of the properties to be dynamic- and it not works, the message have not sended.

at appender:

```
  <to value="%property{emailTo}" />
```

at C#:

```
  log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["emailTo"] = "myAddress@myComp.com";
        ILog emailLog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("EmailLogger"); 
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(emailLog.Logger.Repository);

        emailLog.Error("test aaa");
```

Comment: If you want to configure some or all fields of the `SmtpAppender` [dynamically, you can look at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67433757/11671912)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell log4net that the property uses a "pattern string":

```
<to type="log4net.Util.PatternString"  value="%property{emailTo}" />
```

From the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.PatternString.html):

> This string has embedded patterns that are resolved and expanded when
>   the string is formatted.

Comment: Is there a way to create and append an SMTP Appender to the log4net without and configuration in web.config file.

Comment: @CengizAraz yes you can add one programatically

Comment: Is there any reference that you can add here? Because all I saw through my searches people add the SmtpAppender into the config file and either override SendBuffer() or Append() method. I want to create something dynamic and to be able to define all properties of that SmtpAppender in my C# file. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey @CengizAraz, if you're still searching, check out [my answer on overriding the SmtpAppender programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67433757/11671912).