# When does PatternString type get resolved in Log4NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, log4net

Suppose I have the following CustomSmtpAppender:

```
 <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="EmgNetExt.EMGSmtpAppender, EmgNetExt">  
...
 <subject type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="ERROR: %property{app_sub_name}" />
...
</appender>
```

So every time it sends an e-mail the %propery{app_sub_name} is resolving to an empty string. It is initially set to an empty string but then as the app runs the value changes to mark where the app is at a point in time in case an error happens. So I caused an error to happen and at a debug point I see that:

`log4net.GlobalContext.Properties("app_sub_name")` returns the correct value but my e-mail still comes out with the blank "app_sub_name".

So I am thinking that maybe log4net resolves the PatternString **JUST ONCE** when it initially reads the log4net.config but I can't confirm this or maybe I am missing a step and doing something wrong. When does log4net resolve the subject element? Only initially, when it loads the log4net.config or every time that the appender is invoked? Is there a way to force it to resolve every time the appender is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appenders are parsed and evaluated only once when configuring log4net (eg. through a `XmlConfigurator.Configure` call), so as you have guessed the subject will be evaluated once. This is supported by the `Subject` property of the `SmtpAppender` being a string rather than a type with dynamic capabilities. Additionally `To` and `From` properties are also not dynamic, so you wouldn't be able to change them during execution. Even if you use a `PatternString` it is converted to string through type converters when parsing the configuration.

There is no way to change this behavior using the current `SmtpAppender` since properties are non-dynamic. You could create an appender that uses dynamic values to populate the fields of the email.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902060/configure-or-extend-log4net-smtpappender-with-custom-subjects

Comment: @sgmoore thanks for the pointer. I didn't look to see if one was already existing; I find that log4net lacks a centralized hub to expose this kind of additional devs

Comment: @sgmoore The article confirms that changing the subject to a dynamic value was the way to go: "I modified the Subject property from a string to a ILayout."